# How to calculate the sum of ID^ with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have two different IDs. One auto increment (using jquery) from an ID called id="H+currentRow+"(+currentRow+ is the current row). And another that does an ajax request to PHP that appends the form with an id="Z#"(# will be depending on the ID in the database).

Ive done this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").change(function(){ 
var sum=0;
    $("[id^=H]").each(function(){

     sum=sum+(+parseInt(this.value));
    });

var sum2=0;
    $("[id^=Z]").each(function(){

     sum2=sum2+(+parseInt(this.value));
    });

var total = sum + sum2;
    if(isNaN(total)) {
        var total = 0;
    }

$("#total").text(total);

});
});
```

But thats not working. It works for the first fields but it work for anything else thats being appended. Anyone know whats going on and why its not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you bind an event direct to an element, new elements appended to page will not trigger the event. you have to bind a parent element where inputs are appended to.

Try this bind:

```
$('body').on('change', 'input', function () {
    // your code remain the same here...
});
```

you can be more specifc than `body`, binding the event to parent elements of input.

Comment: Thanks @Callebe but it stil results on the same thing with change. When the the pre-filled value comes in and append, it doesnt update the value until I click and change the value. Blur works some sort but it only works when click the box and get out.

Comment: I got it to work using mousemove function. It works but still doesnt load automatically. It will do lol

Comment: You can define a method to update the value, call it inside the `change` event function, and call it inside `$(document).ready` function.